# Python: how to compute the distance between all the points in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
df
       lat           lon    idx
0   42.363427   -71.096072   0
1   42.360000   -71.090000   1
2   42.360000   -71.090000   2
3   42.364733   -71.095312   3
4   42.360000   -71.090000   4
```

I would like to compute the distance in km between all the points. This what I am doing

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 3956 # Radius of earth in miles. Use 6371 for kilometers
    return c * r
```

this what I trying

```
RES = []
for i in df.index:
    s1 = df[df.index == i]
    for j in stop.index:
        if j > i:
            s2 = df[df.index == j]
            lon1 = s1.lon.values
            lon2 = s2.lon.values
            lat1 = s1.lat.values
            lat2 = s2.lat.values
            distance = haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)
            RES.append([s1.idx, s2.idx, distance, lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
```

I am wondering if there is a way to avoid the loop.

Something like

```
RES = df.apply(heversine(df.lon, df.lat, df.lon[1:], df.lat[1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a matrix having all the distances thanks to [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) :

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
distance_matrix = cdist(df.values[:, 0:2], df.values[:, 0:2], 'euclidean') # you may replace euclidiean by another distance metric among the metrics available in the link above
```

Output :

```
[[0.         0.00697234 0.00697234 0.00151104 0.00697234]
 [0.00697234 0.         0.         0.00711468 0.        ]
 [0.00697234 0.         0.         0.00711468 0.        ]
 [0.00151104 0.00711468 0.00711468 0.         0.00711468]
 [0.00697234 0.         0.         0.00711468 0.        ]]
```

If you want then to get the results in a dataframe rather than in a matrix, you can simply do :

```
pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix)
```